# Not able to receive geofence alert in android

Tags: android, google-play-services, geofencing, android-geofence

I have implemented Geofencing in my app using the android demo(http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html). The problem is that i get accurate alert notification only when google maps or any another app which request for location update is open and that with GPS enabled. I don’t get any alert notification when my 3g or wifi is on. I have kept 1000m as geofence radius. Even when my 3g or wifi is on and i am standing in the middle of the geofence area i don’t get alert notification.

Do I need to request location update manually or it takes time for geofence to trigger a alert notification?

Answer (score 2):

My geofences work OK when I first call `requestLocationUpdates` and in the `onLocationChanged` callback add geofences to the `LocationClient`

So your assumption most likely is correct that manual update is needed.

I have also set polling of location to 1 min or 100m, so my application behaves like maps, getting the location all the time. API for this is `LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener)`

Comment: I use both GPS_PROVIDER and NETWORK_PROVIDER for location